# Can we create an AWS direct between AWS datacenter in Frankfurt and on premise datacenter in China?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

**Background**

We have an app that will write into a postgres db hosted in Frankfurt datacenter.
The app is installed in each of the 8 sites we have around the world, from China, Korea, India , Germany, France and Mexico.

When connecting from Europe, to the Frankfurt database, the response times are good. However, when connecting from the two sites I have in the northern part of China, the response time are plain slow.
The China great firewall is delaying the response time and adding to that, the distance is a decisive factor.

After massive search and Q/A sessions, I'd discovered that AWS is offering a solution called `Direct Connect`. It allows to create a point to point connection between any AWS datacenter and on-premise server that can be located anywhere in the world and here in China.

**Questions are:**

- Can set a direct connect link from the Frankfurt AWS datacenter to
  one of my on-premise site in China?
- What do I need to do except than starting the DX connect service on AWS?

Comment: You really should reach out to AWS sales/support on this. I'd imagine at *some* point it's still going to transit the Great Firewall.

Comment: Yesterday you said the server is in Seoul which is South Korea...

Comment: Hi @Burgi , the aim is to have one database, which is in Frankfurt as said yesterday. But due to latency, I have started a database in Seoul, hoping for bidirectional replication. But AWS does not allowed rep that way. Therefore I'm trying a new way .eg.going for direct connect...

Comment: AWS doesn't prevent replication. RDS may or may not support it, but you can run anything you like on EC2 instances. If the problem is in China maybe you need to have at least a read replica there, if not a full replica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It allows to create a point to point connection between any AWS datacenter and on-premise server that can be located anywhere in the world and here in China.

That is an oversimplification.  It makes such connections possible, but it is not end-to-end.

AWS DirectConnect allows you to connect to the AWS network infrastructure at any one of [a number of datacenters](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/details/).

But the DirectConnect service only includes the connection at the collocation facility. It doesn't provide the necessary transport circuits to haul the traffic to your location from the interconnection point if you don't already have facilities in place.

Your inquiries should be directed to one of their partnered providers.

> If you don’t have preexisting infrastructure at one of our AWS Direct Connect locations, don’t worry. AWS has a growing list of APN Technology and Consulting Partners (formerly called AWS Direct Connect Solution Providers) who can assist you in using the AWS Direct Connect service. These APN Partners can help you establish network circuits between an AWS Direct Connect location and your datacenter, office, or colocation environment, or assist you in constructing a hybrid environment.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/details/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Michael's answer.

The answer to your question is no in the manner that you have asked it.

1) Direct Connect provides point to point dedicated private connectivity from a company's office to an AWS Data Center (region). You pay for the private link to AWS. Unless you have huge funds this means a connection to an AWS data center in China.

2) To connect from AWS China to another region outside of China, you will need to setup a VPN.

3) You will need to register the VPN used to transport traffic from China to outside China.

4) Currently, VPNs are only allowed to transfer traffic back to a company's corporate office.

The typical usage of AWS for region to region connectivity for your goals does not apply. AWS China and AWS need to be treated as two different vendors. The easiest solution is to create a VPN from your China office to your corporate headquarters, route traffic from your corporate office to other AWS regions and apply for the correct licenses in China for the VPN. Your Internet vendor provides the backbone that transfers traffic thru the China Firewall. This could be AWS, Alibaba, China Telcom, etc. You will not be able to use low cost pubic Internet for your VPN traffic on the China side.

Given the costs involved, government licensing and regulations and that all paperwork and communications must be done in Chinese, you will need to retain a partner to manage this for you unless you have the staff in your China office trained specifically in this area.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed, it would have been very costly. I've checked the cost and actually, it was way more expensive when you add the VPN or additional cost. This is the reason the project was not carried forward :)